# Odoo currency rounding with too many decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, rounding, odoo-14

I am trying to convert one currency float to another, but for some reason the resulting number (even though it is correct) has too many decimals.

I am converting EUR float 36.75 (currency decimal rounding = 0.01) into CZK float (currency decimal rounding = 0.01)

Example

```
eur_currency._convert(36.75, move.company_currency_id, move.company_id, move.date)
```

result = 942.3100000000001

desired output = 942.31

Comment: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) in python docs should explain why you see so many digits after `.` in effect of arithemtic operations on `float`s in pythons, but I do not have knowledge how this issue should be handled in `odoo-14`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use round:

```
round(result, 2)
```

Comment: I don't understand the review comment. This seems like a good answer to me, and is exactly how I solve this problem in my code.